# EComDev PHPUnit get and set session data

Tags: session, ecomdev-phpunit, magic-getter

How do you test setting and getting a session variable in PHPUnit/EComDev? This is what I've so far in my test method:

```
$checkoutSession = $this->getModelMock('checkout/session');
$checkoutSession->expects($this->any())->method('getData')->with('number')->will($this->returnCallback(array($this, 'getNumber')));
$checkoutSession->expects($this->any())->method('setData')->will($this->returnCallback(array($this, 'setNumber')));
```

In the test class, I've defined the following:

```
protected $_number = 5;

public function getNumber()
{
    return $this->_number;
}

public function setNumber()
{
    $args = func_get_args();
    $key = $args[0];
    $value = $args[1];

    $this->_number = $value;
}
```

This works in the code being tested:

```
$checkoutSession = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session');
$number = $checkoutSession->getData('number'); //5
$checkoutSession->setData('number', $number+1);
$number2 = $checkoutSession->getData('number'); //6
```

However, getting the variable with Magento's magic method does not:

```
$number = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getNumber();//this is null
```

How does one mock Magento's magic methods?

Answer (score 1):

In the given example, **all** methods are replaced by mock implementations. No existing `Mage_Checkout_Model_Session` method ever gets called, including `getNumber()` and `__call()`.

There is no return value defined for `getNumber()` so you get `null`.

To create a stub that returns configured values for `getData` and `setData` only (while executing all other methods normally), add these method names as second parameter:

```
$checkoutSession = $this->getModelMock(
    'checkout/session',
    array('init', 'getData', 'setData')
);
```